# Rewrite in Nextjs is a Proxy?

Tags: next.js

I just want to know how to work rewrite function on next.js for solving CORS error.
I tried to find that contents about it on the official site but I couldn't.
I think it works like below. can you find any offcial thing, not someone thought ??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPQrR.png)

I already asked on their github but nobody answer yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.